# Get data from opened html tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-scraping

My point is to get some data from a html page (text and tables). However, when I am using the different functions in Google Sheets (`importxml`; `importhtml`); those ones are not working ("Could not fetch the URL"). I tried many alternative methods using google sheets by none are working due to website type (I guess).

In this way, as alternative option, I want to know if there is a specific code line(s) in Google Apps Script to copy values from open web page (opened in a Google Chrome tab) in order to paste those values in Google Sheets tab (opened in another tab of Google Chrome). I think this method will avoid to open the website & consequently the same error as import functions in Google Sheets.

---

As additional comments the `UrlFetch` is not permitted by my admin

Comment: As additional comments the UrlFetch is not permitted by my admin :(

Comment: Then your admin probably does not want you to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

As your admin doesn't allow the use of UrlFetch it's not possible because Google Apps Script is not able access the opened tabs of your web browser.

Reference

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

Answer (score -1):

Apps Script is just javascript so you could use a web data API like https://rapidapi.com/fusioncow11/api/web-data1
and you could implement it with something like:

```
const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        data: 'https://www.google.com/',
        style: 'html',
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'keyhere',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'web-data1.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
};

fetch('https://web-data1.p.rapidapi.com/', options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: It's not accurate. While Google Apps Script uses JavaScript as programming language, it doesn't support the Fetch API as well other Web APIs.